# How to do Kernel density analysis in QGIS 1.7?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, density

Do someone have some suggestion? We would like to tray Kernel Density analysis as we did with ArcGis using QGIS?

Comment: you can check out [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6153/how-do-you-use-grasss-v-kernel),too

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? KD analysis in ArcGIS is not the same as GRASS's v.kernel, but v.surf may give better results.

Answer (score 5):

Kernel density analysis is possible using the GRASS plugin v.kernel tool. For documentation check http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/v.kernel.html