# Create a heatmap with R for printed media

Tags: r, heat-map

I am looking for a way to represent density points using heatmaps in R for printed media (e.g. using Rmarkdown to generate a PDF).

The map should have a basemap (OpenStreetMap or Stammen) and instead of presenting all points I want them to be presented as a density heatmap overlayed.

I know there are several ways to create heatmaps in R, like `leaflet.extras`'s [`addHeatmap()`](https://bhaskarvk.github.io/leaflet.extras/reference/heatmap.html) for HTML maps. Unfortunately, they can't be exported to PDF (or other formats different to html).

`ggmap`, on the contrary, is aimed for printed maps, but unfortunately, it has two main problems: 1) it requires google API key (I do not want to do do it, neither I want to use google services) 2) it is quite cumbersome, as it requires knowing bounding box beforehand and, since I have to do plenty of maps, I need an automated way to get that bounding box (ideally without requiring other packages, such as `osmdata`'s [`getbb()`](https://docs.ropensci.org/osmdata/reference/getbb.html)).

`tmap` would be a great solution, as it allows re-using same code for printed and interactive maps, but I haven't found any documentation about generating heatmaps.

Is there any way to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: What do you understand as a "heatmap"? To me its a kernel-smoothed density of points. You can compute that as a raster using several techniques, then all you need to do is plot a raster using tmap. Look at how to do point density estimation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ggplot` to create a kernel density map. Have a look at an [old question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39074/whats-the-best-way-to-produce-a-density-map-from-weighted-points-in-qgis) on kernel density maps for some discussion on what 'heatmap' means in several contexts.

```
# Setup ----
library(ggplot2)

# Reproducible data ----
obs <- data.frame(x = 35 + (rnorm(100)/5), y = -2.5 + (rnorm(100)/5),
                  count = rbinom(100, 10, 0.4))
obs <- rbind(obs, 
             data.frame(x = 34 + (rnorm(100)/5), y = -3 + (rnorm(100)/5),
                        count = rbinom(100, 10, 0.4))
             )

# Plot ----
ggplot(obs, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = 'OrRd', direction = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  geom_point(cex = 0.5)
```

[image]

For a tiled basemap you can use the stamen maps:

```
library(ggmap)
osm <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(min(obs$x), min(obs$y), max(obs$x), max(obs$y)))
g <- ggmap(osm)
g +   stat_density_2d(data = obs, aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE, , alpha = 0.5) + coord_cartesian() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = 'BuPu', direction = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the solution and disambiguation! I love the idea of only using ggplot, with no further package. However, I will explore how to add a basemap to your code before accepting it.

Comment: Could you edit your question and describe what else you need on the map?

Comment: The additional code I added should solve it - though it's annoying to have to use the coord_cartesian to reproject