# How to use v.kernel?

Tags: grass-gis, density

I am studying the use of GRASS GIS within QGIS and I need a little help with the understanding of the `v.kernel` module.
I didn't find any human help within the manual (very cryptic)

I have a point data vector and I need to study the density of the points
distribution in my mapset using a bandwidth of 1000 meters.

How do I set the parameter `<stddeviation>`, or in other words ... what is this parameter related to?
What is the correct use of this parameter in relation with the settings
of the bandwidth?
Can I simply set the parameter with a value of 1000?

Comment: check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/how-to-interpret-grass-v-kernel-results?rq=1 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6153/how-do-you-use-grasss-v-kernel?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the links to the answers, actually I have already read this answers but they don't help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Standard deviation is one parameter that is needed when using Gaussian Kernel Shape. Depends on how big your standard deviation is, it will influence the estimation value. Refer to this [post](http://www.geodose.com/2017/11/qgis-heatmap-using-kernel-density.html) to get more understanding about Kernel Density Estimation