# V.kernel not working correctly in grass-6.4.2

Tags: raster, grass-gis, density

I am using grass-6.4.2 for generation of heat maps of crime data. For testing purpose, I created a vector layer from my places shapefile which is a point data.The places shapefile contains more than 3000 data.I used **v.kernel** command for generation of raster map as follows:

```
g.region rows=20 cols=20
v.kernel input=Places@PERMANENT output=raster1 stddeviation=0.001
```

But the output was a rectangle. I increased the `stddeviation` value step by step to 10000. The output has `Maximum value in output: 1.591528e-11.` but the raster image is completely wrong. Please help me in solving this issue.

---

I checked with rows=600 and columns=600 with a standard deviation of 1000. Here is the output I got:

```
(Thu Nov 15 11:05:14 2012) Command finished (0 sec)                             
(Thu Nov 15 11:06:05 2012)                                                      
v.kernel input=Places@PERMANENT output=raster3 stddeviation=10000               
STDDEV: 10000.000000
RES: 1324.680000    ROWS: 600   COLS: 600

Writing output raster map using smooth parameter=10000.000000.

Normalising factor=648263501.877776.
Maximum value in output: 1.589441e-09.
(Thu Nov 15 11:06:07 2012) Command finished (2 sec)
```

All I get is several rings with different colors radiating from the center.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain how you know the result "is completely wrong" and in what way it is erroneous. It is striking that you use only 20*20 = 400 cells to represent 3000 points. Another interesting aspect is the `stddeviation` value of 0.001. If the data are in meters, that is far too small; if the data are in degrees, you will get incorrect results because you haven't projected them. You might like to review the related threads, [How to interpret GRASS v.kernel results?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1553) and [How do you use GRASS's v.kernel?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6153).

Comment: Re the edit: This sounds like the output is correct.  What happens when you set the standard deviation to a value somewhere between 1 and 10?  (Note that the output indicates you set it to 10,000, not 1000.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the parameter name is confusing. Hence, upon discussion and a [ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/1828),
'stddeviation' has been renamed to 'radius' with the kernel radius in map units.

Comment: ... hence it is solved for GRASS 7. In GRASS 6 it cannot be renamed for consistency reasons. Hope this has solved the problem.